# How set delegate for UIViewController in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Please help me,

I have use https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController. It is really cool.
My storyboard design like this:
`UINavigationController => LocationViewController => DetailViewController.`(I can't upload image because I've not enough 10 reputation).

How I set delegate for LocationViewController. I just know how I find it.

```
UINavigationController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"showPopup"];
if ([vc.topViewController isKindOfClass:[LocationViewController class]]) {

}
```

Thanks so much!!!
Problem like: https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController/issues/51#issuecomment-65695610

Comment: Make `LocationViewController` is property and then set delegate to it. Otherwise the delegate may not work.

Comment: I do like this. LocationViewController *locationView = (LocationViewController*)vc.topViewController;
    NSLog(@"%@",locationView);
    locationView.delegate = self;
But it doesn't work